# how i can optimize long if else to optimized version

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my following code i am setting status of two scope variables based on Anding operation.

Depending on the key im calling the relevant method (the difference in both methods is checking prop3.

I feel it has quite redudant code but not sure how i can optimize it.
Any idea how i can achieve my objective with short code?

```
if(key =='White')
    _checktests1();
else
    _checktests2 ();

var _checktests1 = function () {
    if ($scope.test.Prop1 == "one" && $scope.test.Prop2 == "two")
        $scope.checkWhiteStatus = true;
    else
        $scope.checkWhiteStatus = false;

    if ($scope.test.Prop1 == "three" && $scope.test.Prop2 == "four" )
        $scope.checkGreenStatus = true;
    else
        $scope.checkGreenStatus = false;
}
var _checktests2 = function () {
    if ($scope.test.Prop1 == "one" && $scope.test.Prop2 == "two" && $scope.test.Prop3 == "five")
        $scope.checkWhiteStatus = true;
    else
        $scope.checkWhiteStatus = false;

    if ($scope.test.Prop1 == "three" && $scope.test.Prop2 == "four" $scope.test.Prop6 == "six")
        $scope.checkGreenStatus = true;
    else
        $scope.checkGreenStatus = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do :

```
$scope.checkWhiteStatus = ($scope.test.Prop1 == "one" && $scope.test.Prop2 == "two" && (key =='White' || $scope.test.Prop3 == "five"));

$scope.checkGreenStatus = ($scope.test.Prop1 == "three" && $scope.test.Prop2 == "four" && (key =='White' || $scope.test.Prop6 == "six"));
```

Comment: You might also do `var t = $scope.test;` to save some more letters.

Comment: @Thom-x, But sometime $scope.test.Prop3 has null in my case. Also, i have tried this way but the issue is if you assign something to Prop6 and later on you are expecting null it will fail.

Comment: @immirza: Not sure what you are refering to. There are no assignments anywhere; and this code is exactly equivalent to the one presented in the question. If there are problems, the original code has them as well.

Comment: @Bergi, my scope variables are updated with valies when paged loads. so Assume all scope variable has either proper value or null.

Comment: Then `$scope.checkWhiteStatus` and `$scope.checkGreenStatus` = false. What do you want ?